# Calculations between the object properties that belongs to same class in Python

Tags: python, class

```
class Person():

     def __init__(self,name,age,salary):
        self.age =age
        self.name=name
        self.salary=salary

mike = Person('mike',20,2000)
john = Person('john',25,2500)

totalSalary=mike.salary + john.salary
print(totalSalary)
```

I would like find total salary that a firm pays to all employees, but this solution does not look a good way as maybe 5000 employees could be working for the company. So what would be the best way to cope with it?

Comment: can keep it in a dictionary ? a dict with key name, age and salary and have sum of all key salary if you don’t have any other purpose

Comment: @sarath The name is redundant really, as it's an attribute on the object already. Just creating a list would do…

Comment: How this instances are created?

Comment: Looks like some homework question so I won't directly answer the question. Take a look at python lists:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
A simple for loop on the list should answer your question. Next step take a look at `sum()`and list comprehension in python.

Comment: I am a new self learner. I was wondering if there is a way to create a method in the class to calculate this sum automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
totalSalary = sum(person.salary for person in [mike, john])
```

Output

```
4500
```